# slide to unlock in sencha touch(ext js)

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I want to create somthing similar to iphone slide to unlock in sencha touch (Ext js); as i searching i found it can be done easily with jquery as mentioned here ([iPhone “slide to unlock” Text in WebKit/CSS3](http://css-tricks.com/slide-to-unlock/); in this case it is using jquery draggable feature i know there is draggable component in ext js but how could i implement something like example that goes smoothly.

```
  xtype: 'panel',
 title: 'Drop a Panel Here',
 listeners: { render: initializeDropTarget },
 cls: 'x-dd-drop-ok'
```

my questions are how can i limit directions of draggable in ext js?